# How to get the value of an input field in a function via angular?

Tags: angular

I Have defined an input field like below:

```html
    <label>Enter more months</label>
    <input #mname type='text' id="mname" >
    <button (click)="addMonth(mname.value)" style="height: 30px;"></button>
```

on clicking on the button I want the value of the input field to be printed on the console ,for which i am defining  a function as below:

```js
    addMonth(mname){
        console.log(mname.value);
    }
```

But I am not able to pass the value of the  field. How can I do so?

Comment: I don't understand. Your code is perfectly valid and does exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have pass the value not the input element reference

```
<button (click)="addMonth(mname.value)" style="height: 30px;">
```

now you have the value itself

```
addMonth(value :string){
    console.log(value);
}
```

if you pass the element reference like this `(click)="addMonth(mname)"` then you can access to value property

```
addMonth(elm :HTMLInputElement){
    console.log(elm.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) for this.

Also please look at the below code, found on this link.

In your html

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name" #ctrl="ngModel" required>
```

In your component, please add a definition for your input. e.g.

```
name: string = '';
```

This is called double binding, and any change in the input will be reflected in the variable.